# How do I make two characters not run through each other when colliding in PYGAME?

Tags: python, pygame, game-physics

I'm creating my first game and I am having some trouble handling collisions. What I have is a 2 player game played on the same keyboard, awsd and updownleftright controls.  When the two players collide, I want them to not be able to move through each other.  I'm having trouble figuring that out.

```
player_one_pos = [300,310]
player_two_pos = [600,310]

def detect_collision(player_one_pos, player_two_pos):
    p1_x = player_one_pos[0]
    p1_y = player_one_pos[1]
    p2_x = player_two_pos[0]
    p2_y = player_two_pos[1]
    if (p1_x + player_width/2) == (p2_x - player_width/2):
        return True
    return False

if detect_collision(player_one_pos, player_two_pos):
    ## players collide, can't go through each other
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get it done by adding an and statement. This fix should suffice for now.

```
if key_pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < (goal_right[0] - player_width) and (x != a - player_width):
    x += speed_of_travel
if key_pressed[pygame.K_a] and a > (goal_left[0] + goal_width) and (a != x + player_width):
    a -= speed_of_travel
```